# Ideas invited for speeding this code using multi threading ,paritioner

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

How do i multi thread this simple operation of adding all elements to the hashtable collectionction?

```
foreach (var x in listx) //List of x
{
    String temp1 = x.sc;
    String temp2 = x.key;
    Nullable<int> temp3 = x.val;

    if ((null != temp2) && (string.Empty != temp2) && (int.MinValue != temp3) && "Fetch" == temp1)
    {
        if (false == htTempVal.ContainsKey(temp2.Trim()))
            htTempVal.Add(temp2.Trim(), temp3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Backgroudworker. Split your list into however many threads you want to use. Send a chunck of the split array to each backgroundworker.

Comment: Well, hashtables aren't threadsafe, so you can't add multiple items at the same time.  Since that portion will need to be serialized there isn't much room here for concurrency.

Comment: banging, I'd rather use a Thread pool for that than an array of BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: Are you locked in to the data types?

Comment: the dictionary has about a million records after the loop is executed, i tried doing a parallel.foreach loop but i seem to be getting index out of bounds exception , not sure y . .. the loop takes quite some time to execute, dont have the stats now with me, but was wondering if i cud break it up and load it faster... Ideas are welcome

Comment: nope, i m not locked in to the datatypes.

Comment: This code snippet should not take a particularly long time to run, even with a million records.  Run a profiler to see what is taking up significant portions of the runtime to see where the problem lies, specifically.  I doubt it's with the snippet you've shown here.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of quick performance improvements:

(1)  Trim x.Key when you assign temp2 rather than trimming temp2 in your loop.

(2)  Is it possible to make htTempVal a HashSet?  HashSets are optimized and allow you to just Add without having to worry about checking if the key exists.  I've seen amazing performance improvements by overriding GetHashCode for my objects and using the HashSet.

These are minor and easy but if you have approx. 1 million records, it may start to interfere with performance.

Comment: Regarding (2) isn't that HashSet? HashTable will throw on an Add if the key already exists.

Comment: Shoot you're correct.  Sorry about that and thanks for the callout. I got my hash collections confused.  Updated the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Find a hash table that is threadsafe?

Can you sort your items first, then add only the unique ones?  There is probably a parallel sort.  You could then skip the ContainsKey() test.

Alternatively, why not skip that test anyway and just ignore the error if there is one.

Finally, how could a million items be slow?  Something else must be happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, replacing the hash table with a `ConcurrentDictionary`. It's not guaranteed that you will get any speedup however, since you are just basically doing an atomic operation in a loop:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<String, Nullable<int>> htTempVal = 
           new ConcurrentDictionary<String, Nullable<int>>();

Parallel.ForEach (listx,
  x =>
  {
      String temp1 = x.sc;
      String temp2 = x.key.Trim();
      Nullable<int> temp3 = x.val;

      if ((null != temp2) && (string.Empty != temp2) && 
          (int.MinValue != temp3) && "Fetch" == temp1)
      {
          htTempVal.GetOrAdd(temp2, temp3);
      }
  });
```

`ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` atomically checks and adds a key-value pair if it does not exist or returns the value if it's already in the dictionary (which you can ignore).